# c# exception handeling (catching all together, sorting them in a different method)

Tags: c#, exception

Im working on my exception handeling at the moment.
Im using

```
try
{
   stuff();
}
catch (NullReferenceException ex)
{
   logTheError(ex, "NullReferenceException", "functionname");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   logTheError(ex, "Exception", "functionname");
}
```

I want to catch all exceptions here and handle them in the logTheError-function (which already writes an entry to a database for later usage). But I could not manage to check an exception there if it is e.g. a NullReferenceException.

```
if (ex == NullReferenceException)
or
if (ex.GetType == NullReferenceException)
```

This did not work. I think theres a pretty simple solution for it.
I also want to know, If I can get the name of the exception (perhaps this is the type?)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `if(ex is NullReferenceException){...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
try
{
    stuff();
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    logTheError( ex, "Exception", "functionname" );
}
```

And then in the logging function:

```cs
if ( ex is NullReferenceException )
    handleNullreference();
else if ( ex is KeyNotFoundException )
    handleKeyNotFound();
// ...
else
    handleUnknown();
```